# Python requests post doing nothing

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) and [cfscrape](https://github.com/Anorov/cloudflare-scrape) library to login to https://kissanime.to/Login

```
'''Login to website'''
def login(self, usr, pw):
    login_url = 'https://kissanime.to/Login'
    sess = requests.Session()

    # login credentials
    payload = {
        'username': usr,
        'password': pw,
        'redirect': ''
    }

    # Creating cfscrape instance of the session
    scraper_sess = cfscrape.create_scraper(sess)
    a = scraper_sess.post(login_url, data=payload)
    print(a.text)
    print(a.status_code)
```

`a.text` gives me the same login page
`a.status_code` gives me 200

That means my login is not working at all. Am I missing something? According to chrome's network monitor, I should also get `status code 302`

POST DATA image:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using [mechanicalsoup](https://github.com/hickford/MechanicalSoup)

Code:

```
import mechanicalsoup

'''Login to website'''
def login(self, usr, pw):
    login_url = 'https://kissanime.to/Login'

    # Creating cfscrape instance
    self.r = cfscrape.create_scraper()
    login_page = self.r.get(login_url)

    # Creating a mechanicalsoup browser instance with 
    # response object of cfscrape
    browser = mechanicalsoup.Browser(self.r)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(login_page.text, 'html.parser')

    # grab the login form
    login_form = soup.find('form', {'id':'formLogin'})

    # find login and password inputs
    login_form.find('input', {'name': 'username'})['value'] = usr
    login_form.find('input', {'name': 'password'})['value'] = pw

    browser.submit(login_form, login_page.url)
```

Answer (score -1):

This content is from Requests Documentation:

> Many web services that require authentication accept HTTP Basic Auth. This is the simplest kind, and Requests supports it straight out of the box.
>
> ```
> requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))
> ```

You have to send the payload as JSON..

```
import requests,json
'''Login to website'''
def login(self, usr, pw):
    login_url = 'https://kissanime.to/Login'
    sess = requests.Session()

    # login credentials
    payload = {
        'username': usr,
        'password': pw,
        'redirect': ''
    }

    # Creating cfscrape instance of the session
    scraper_sess = cfscrape.create_scraper(sess)
    a = scraper_sess.post(login_url, data=json.dumps(payload))
    print(a.text)
    print(a.status_code)
```

Reference: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/

Comment: Can you try logging in with Selenium Webdriver

Comment: @min2bro yeah, I have tried with Selenium and it works. But it's slow. So, I wanted to do with reqeusts.

Comment: I had actually tried this already, and I just tried again. Same outcome. :(

Comment: You will need to add the username and password as authentication header to the request. You can find more details here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/